# I need to know when hibernate has completed its transaction

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity that has a CallBackListener registered using postPersist and postUpdate. The listener takes the entity and submits the ID to a JMS queue which perform further processing. The message submission and consumption are so fast that they're occurring before the original session has completed it's transaction.

As a result the MDB either can't find the entity or the entity is stale. What I really want is a way to have the MDB check to verify that the original transaction is complete before consuming the message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to register an instance of `org.hibernate.Interceptor` with the `SessionFactory` or `Session`, and post the message to the queue in the `afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx)` method after consulting `Transaction.wasCommitted`. In the `afterTransaction` method you might have to access the ID of your entity in some global threadlocal.

Comment: I did some testing with that and it seems to be intercepting at the DB transaction level. In other words, it fires after it's committed the data to the DB rather than when the java transaction is committed. I'm still digging.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better that way i.e. sending the JMS message after the DB txn is committed? That way the MDB will see the committed data. Or are you planning to implement a transaction engine taking input as JMS messages and using a RDBMS for persistence?